# What is Android Service?

Tags: java, android

Can someone explain for me, what is android service and how to use it? I know that there are some kinds of service, such as: foreground service, bound service,... What are the differences between them?

I'm trying to learn about android but struggle with documents provided by google.

Comment: :b srr, i put this question for myself for taking note. But thanks for you advice.

Comment: Here's a Medium article that briefly explains what a system service is, if that's what you are wondering: https://medium.com/android-news/system-service-in-aosp-750007d39555

Comment: yeah, i will take a look later.

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 types of services

- Foreground

Foreground service is use to do some task when your application is closed mainly. you have to make notification to make sure this kind
service runninng in background.

ex : Music Player, File sharing, File downloading

you can create simply background service from android studio

*File > new > service > service*

then add like follwing command

```
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d("Foreground Service","Service On Start command Run");

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent intentx = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,notificationIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);

        String CHANNEL_ID = getString(R.string.channel_id);
        Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(this,CHANNEL_ID)
                .setContentTitle("hello Service Running!")
                .setContentText("Some Descriptions")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon_main)
                .setContentIntent(intentx).build();
        startForeground(199807,notification);
        return START_STICKY;
    }
```

- Background

These kind of services are running on background when application running in foreground. because this service was killed by os when application
was killed by users

ex : synchronizations in online app,validate user details continuously by background when user works with app

you can create simply background service from android studio

*File > new > service > service*

then add follwing command

```
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return START_NOT_STICKY
    }
```

- Bound

A service is bound when an application component binds to it by calling bindService(). A bound service offers a client-server interface
that allows components to interact with the service, send requests, receive results, and even do so across processes with interprocess
communication (IPC). A bound service runs only as long as another application component is bound to it. Multiple components can bind to
the service at once, but when all of them unbind, the service is destroyed.

foreground and background services are explain by my own. but I didn't work with bound service so I copied this note from google.

I'm not mension here long running tasks as service. you can manage long running tasks with android workmanager.

Answer (score 0):

*(Here it just a question for myself for taking note)*

> **Service** is an `android application component` that perform long-running operations in the background.

- There are 3 types of services: `Foreground`, `Background` and `Bound`.

#### Foreground

> service performs operation that **noticeable to user** (must display a notification).

- The notification of Foreground service cannot be dismissed (unless service is stopped or removed).

#### Background

> service performs operation that **isn't directly noticed by the user**.

#### Bound

> a service is bound to an app component by using `bindService()`.

- A bound service is a server in **client-server interface** that allows components (activities...) to interact with service:

  - send requests
  - receive responses
  - interprocess communication (IPC).
- A bound service lives only while there is a component bound to it.
- Multiple components can bind to a service at once, but when all of them unbind. ***-> Service is destroyed***

*(Service can run in the background, even when the user is not interacting with app. So it is important to put it in mind that only create a service only if it is necessary.)*

- If a service is used, it will run in app's main thread by default. So creating a new thread within that service is crucial, since there is a chance that service performs intensive or blocking operations.

### Android Service LifeCycle

[image: Android Service LifeCycle]

- A service started with `startService()` will active util `onDestroy()` method was called. (even when there is no bound component to that service.)
- A service started with `bindService()` will be destroyed when there is no components bound to it.

#### System management with services

- Android system stops a service only when memory is **low** and it must recover resources for the activity that is more focus on.
- If the service is bound to an activity that has user focus, or it is declared to run in the foreground, it is less likely to be killed.
- System will lower long-running service's position over time. -> higher chance to be killed by system.
- If the system killed a service, it will restart it as soon as resources become available (also depend on return value of that service.)